# How does a whipped cream charger work?

Tags: equipment, cream, whipped-cream, whipper

I recently got an iSi whipped cream container that charges with nitrous cannisters. I don't really understand how the thing works, which I think would help my use of the system. How does this actually whip the cream upon dispensing? What does shaking do that will make a solid foam / mousse? Why does over shaking turn it in to a solid in the cannister?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The cream whipper relies on gas expansion to work.

When you make whipped cream by beating, you beat fine air bubbles into the cream. The cream traps air and becomes essentially a matrix that holds those bubbles--a foam.

Your gas-charged whipper does the same thing in a totally different way.

When you charge the whipper with gas, there's high gas pressure inside with the cream. The cream will actually absorb the nitrous oxide you put in. Because of the pressure, the gas absorbed can be thought of as really really really small bubbles within the cream. So you have a matrix of gas and cream, but because the bubbles are so small, it's essentially just cream.

Chilled liquids more easily absorb gases at high pressure, which is why it's good to use cold cream and keep the whole unit in the fridge. A limited amount of agitation (shaking) exposes more cream to the gas, improving absorption.

When you release the cream from the device, the absorbed gas expands rapidly. The bubbles get bigger, and your cream to bubble ratio becomes more like the foam that we know as whipped cream. It's really exactly the same thing, only with nitrous oxide instead of plain ol' boring air inside the bubbles.

Why nitrous oxide? As I understand it, it's because it's the cheapest non-toxic, odorless and tasteless gas you can get. Carbon dioxide would almost be a good choice, but unfortunately it's bitter. Not a good match for cream.

Finally, why is shaking too much a bad thing? That one I don't know for sure, but I know what happens when you over-whip cream with the mixer. You make butter. Perhaps the gas or high pressure encourages this conversion, or maybe you're just churning it that much when you over-shake. Either way, I'm sure you've essentially made butter when you shook it too much.

Comment: And incidentally, this is how beer and sodas are often carbonated. Whether you let yeast make the CO2 or you just pump it in, the beverage absorbs CO2 as the pressure of gas increases in the closed container (bottle, keg, whatever). When you open the vessel or pour a mug from the tap, the gas expands, forming larger bubbles that rise to the surface and make a nice foamy head on top.

Comment: Of note is the fact that there *are* very similar devices that operate on CO2; they're called siphons.

Comment: Also, it's surprisingly difficult to make butter by shaking too much.  Shaking too *little* is the more common problem, because the instruction manuals for these things are hyper-cautious.  I'm not even entirely convinced that it's *possible* to make butter with a single charge; it's never happened to me with any amount of shaking.

Comment: @aaronut: Good point on soda siphons. I don't know from how hard it is to make butter within a cream whipper, though, as I don't actually own one. I just know how they work.

Comment: I used to do demonstrations at some historic houses, and when we'd make butter with the kids, we'd just put some cream in a jar, put a lid on it, and let the kids shake it in turns. It actually took quite a bit of shaking to make butter - 15 minutes or more, depending on how energetic the kids were - but the cream was not particularly useful as *whipped* cream long before that.

Comment: So if the cannister starts to just shoot out basic cream, it's because the NO2 is no longer mixed in with the cream and shaking will reincorporate the NO2 in to the cream?

Comment: @yossarian: It depends. If this happens when you're near the bottom of your cream, your problem is most likely that you don't have sufficient gas pressure left in the device to force the remaining cream to absorb some. Putting in another gas cylinder might help there, but there's risk of overpressure for the device. If you're just getting slightly foamy cream earlier on, then yeah--you need to allow more time for the gas to be absorbed, and maybe shake it some to encourage absorption. Don't forget that chilling helps too.

Comment: @yossarian: To be explicit about it: The biggest factor in the cream absorbing the gas is gas pressure inside the whipper device. If that's too low, shaking won't help much. Shaking helps some, but it's really pressure that's your friend.

Comment: I think it must be encouraging absorption, because this happens early in the process. In fact, on the first squeeze, it was too runny. A couple of shakes fixed the issue. After dispensing for a couple of pieces of pie, it started getting runny again. A few shakes fixed it. So I think it must be encouraging absorption, as there was plenty of cream and pressure in both cases.

Comment: It takes quite a bit of doing & forgetting to make butter even in an industrial strength stand mixer.

Comment: @JohnDibling From personal experience, an immersion blender does the job quite easily.

Comment: The cheapest neutral gas would be air - but you wouldn't be able to pack much of it into the cartridges because **N2O (NOT NO2!!! It's POISON!)** has considerably lower vapor pressure, so you can pack much more of it into the cartridge (by liquefying it) or pack the same amount into a much more lightweight cartridge (one to hold liquid air would need to be quite heavy-duty!)

Answer (score 4):

The principle is actually very simple to understand if you take the liquid out of the equation, and imagine that you're just charging the dispenser by itself, empty.

If you remember your high school science, you should remember that:

- Gases, unlike liquids, are highly [compressible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility); and
- A gas expands to fill its container.

A whipped cream *charger* is a sealed container holding a sizable amount of highly **pressurized** gas (nitrous oxide).  When you screw one into the *dispenser*, it punctures the charger, allowing the pressurized gas to expand and enter the dispenser.  Since the dispenser has much higher capacity (volume) than the charger, basic thermodynamics dictates that **most** of the gas will end up in the dispenser.

When you beat eggs, cream, or anything similar, you are gradually incorporating air into the mixture.  [bikeboy's explanation](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11203/how-does-a-whipped-cream-charger-work/11206#11206) of what it means to incorporate air is a fairly good one.  The difference with a cream whipper is that instead of *gradually incorporating* air into the liquid, you are *rapidly forcing* the nitrous oxide into it.  Because the entire apparatus is completely sealed, when you shake it up, the gas has no place to go except into the liquid.

That's really all there is to it.  You're cramming a certain quantity of a liquid into a container with a large amount of gas and forcing the two to mix.  They *will* still separate over time, because the container is not completely full (and the gas would rather occupy the empty space at the top), but shaking it quickly re-incorporates the ingredients.