# What is the right kind of syphon to use for fish batter?

Tags: equipment, batter, foam

[See below re possible dup]

I've seen recipes for fish and chips call for the use of a CO2 syphon for the batter (looking at you, Heston!). So I'm looking to buy a syphon (I don't have one yet).

I haven't seen explicit comments in any of the recipes as to whether it should be a "soda syphon" or a "cream whipper" but they are explicit about use of CO2.

Most of the product web pages suggest CO2 & N2O aren't interchangeable.  I'm not sure if thats due to physical limitations of the devices, or just in the interest of avoiding funny tasting whipped cream or weird looking "soda"!

Soda syphons seem to be a lot cheaper, but I'm doubtful if they would handle fish batter well - presumably they are designed for less viscous liquids like water.

Can one use CO2 cartridges in 'cream whipper' syphons?  They latter would seem better suited to the texture of the batter.

I understand (slightly, anyway) the various issues around taste / texture etc between CO2 and N2O; but have no idea if the cartridges are physically compatible, or if there are critical pressure differences.

---

This was flagged as possible dup of question about interchangeability of CO2 and N2O cartridges.  I don't think it is.  As one of the comments here says, I have specifc use in mind.

I had looked at that question and, unless I misread it, the answers are mainly about the chemistry, as it were, and not the mechanics of the syphons.  They seem to imply that the cartridges are (often) interchangeable; but many of the product web sites say specifically to use one type or the other, but they don't make it clear if that to do with the device or the recipe, as it were.
(Sorry for long explanation here; If I were able to comment on others' questions Id put the comment on the other post).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are N2O and CO2 chargers interchangeable for culinary purposes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30670/are-n2o-and-co2-chargers-interchangeable-for-culinary-purposes)

Comment: Hi RFlack, and welcome! As you have been on SO, you know that the network is strict about the kind of question it takes. I find your main question fully suited for the site, but have to tell you we don't do brand recommendations or big-lists of other possible uses. So I removed those parts, but I really hope we will get good answers to the syphon type question.

Comment: @GdD To me, it doesn't look like a duplicate. That one is about general syphon use. In this question, the OP asks the right type for a specific use case.

Comment: No it’s not a duplicate, to me anyway.  I now see a box inviting me to state that but I need to edit Qu to clarify the difference but I thought I’d done that already!  Last three paras.

Comment: (Sticking my neck out here...).  Looking at the answers to the linked Qu - do they actually answer the question?  They cover the chemistry quite well. But not the mechanics.  For example if one type of charger is at much higher pressure than the other, interchanging could be dangerous if the syphon is flimsy.  I can’t post commentbthere yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get an ISI whipper (no affiliation), the model that can take both hot and cold.  It accepts CO2 or N2O.  They have multiple safety controls built in, are versatile  (especially given your interest in Heston), come in multiple sizes, and are relatively easy to clean.

Comment: I think I know the model you are suggesting.  That's towards the upper end of my price range ($190 Can on Amazon).   Over time, the difference is immaterial, but I don't yet know if this will be one of those gadgets that gets used for 3 months and then languishes at the back of the drawer.  Is there a lower price alternative, in say the $50 - $100 Can range?  Unless the advice here says otherwise, I;d be inclined to forgo ability to use hot liquids, if that helps.

Comment: @RFlack there are other brands at different price points.  ISI is tops.  If you are going to use modernist techniques, as exemplified by Heston, you will likely face hot and cold applications.  It is a bit expensive, but I've had mine for many years...if that helps...