# Can you use CO2 cartridges in a N2O dispenser?

Tags: cream, water, carbonation

UNlike this post ([Are N2O and CO2 chargers interchangeable for culinary purposes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30670/are-n2o-and-co2-chargers-interchangeable-for-culinary-purposes)) I want to know whether you can use the same dispenser for both carbon dioxide and nitrous oxide.

I see that the heads look aesthetically similar but is there any technical difference between downward- and upward-facing spouts?

i.e. what would happen if I put water in a cream dispenser and used a CO2 cartridge instead of cream and a N2O cartridge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes, but check the manufacturers instructions...if you put water (or any liquid) in a whip cream dispenser, and use a CO2 cartridge,  you can carbonate the liquid...though there is some technique to employ if you want a well-carbonated liquid.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "technique"? And what difference does it make that the spout faces down instead of up?

Comment: Number of charges depends on size of dispenser.  Liquid needs to be as cold as possible. Charge once, then slowly release the gas to remove any air in the canister.  Then charge fully and shake like crazy.  Stand upright, slowly release gas without spraying everywhere.  Remove top while holding valve open.  Pour carbonated liquid.

Answer (score 1):

To most reliable use the cream whipping bottle for carbonating beverages,it is totally possible AND it has some great advantages compared to regular "SodaStream"-makers. 1. You can carbonate all liquid material, not only water (like SodaStream do) 2 You can combine the gases to make a nitrogen Stouts, coffees etc.
When charging empty reservoir with gas, remember ventilate/replase the bottle first with gas to get all air out. That is not necessary if you consume the result right away, but if you're keep it in fridge for longer time, it's preventive gas (co2)!

Comment: Thanks. What is a cheap source for CO2 cartridges?